# Type error on Array.Reduce

Tags: arrays, typescript

I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting an error when trying to do some object transformation.

What I am trying to do is take an array of items and using the Array.Reduce method create a new object based off a field within the item. After that I am using the Object.entries.map method to create a new array so I can later iterate over the objects. Code is below.

```
export interface IMenuItem {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    quantity: number;
}

function toItemGroups(items: IMenuItem[]): [{ items: {}; label: string }] {
    const groups: {} = items.reduce((result, item) => {
        const group: [{}] = result[item.category] || [];
        result[item.category] = group.concat(item);
        return result;
    }, {});

    return Object.entries(groups).map(([label, items]) => ({ items, label }));
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

> type { items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }[] is not assignable to type [{ items: {}; label: string }].

This is pretty self explanatory but I cannot seem to figure out what types I need to get this to map correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly because on one hand items is an array of `IMenuItem` whilst on the other its a simple object?

Comment: Why are you returning `[{ items: {}; label: string }]` instead of `{ items: {}; label: string }[]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It told you want type it was expecting so just use that in your function declaration:

```
function toItemGroups(items: IMenuItem[]): { items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }[] {
```

Note that you want the `[]` at the end of the type, to mean array.

`[{ items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }]` would have meant tuple (or an array of length one)

Comment: ahhhh this makes much more sense. thank you for your explanation. The syntax of an array of objects is a little confusing but your explanation helps.

Comment: I'm now getting the following error when I change my return type to: 
`{ items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }[]` 

`{ items: {}; label: string;}[] is not assignable to { items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }[]` 

It's probably something to do with the types that the groups and group are but still can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Your return type for `toItemGroups()` is `[{ items: {}; label: string }]` it should be `{ items: IMenuItem[]; label: string }[]`.  the `items` in the return type is an array of `IMenuItem`